Error during installation with pip install
I'm encountering an issue while trying to install the dependencies for my Python project using pip install pandas==1.1.4 in Windows Poweshell. Then I got an Error like the picture below:

DEPRECATION: Loading egg at d:\data analyst\github\lokalhangatt\pacmann - git\minggu_4\4. advanced data manipulation\pertemuan 8 - data preprocessing pipeline\virenv_preprocessing\lib\site-packages\seaborn-0.11.0-py3.12.egg is deprecated. pip 25.1 will enforce this behaviour change. A possible replacement is to use pip for package installation. Discussion can be found at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/12330
Collecting pandas==1.1.4
  Downloading pandas-1.1.4.tar.gz (5.2 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 5.2/5.2 MB 491.1 kB/s eta 0:00:00
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [32 lines of output]
      <string>:19: DeprecationWarning: pkg_resources is deprecated as an API. See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html
      <string>:45: DeprecationWarning: distutils Version classes are deprecated. Use packaging.version instead.
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "D:\Data Analyst\Github\lokalhangatt\Pacmann - Git\Minggu_4\4. ADVANCED DATA MANIPULATION\Pertemuan 8 - Data Preprocessing Pipeline\virenv_preprocessing\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "D:\Data Analyst\Github\lokalhangatt\Pacmann - Git\Minggu_4\4. ADVANCED DATA MANIPULATION\Pertemuan 8 - Data Preprocessing Pipeline\virenv_preprocessing\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "D:\Data Analyst\Github\lokalhangatt\Pacmann - Git\Minggu_4\4. ADVANCED DATA MANIPULATION\Pertemuan 8 - Data Preprocessing Pipeline\virenv_preprocessing\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-zwgg3cb7\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 334, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=[])
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-zwgg3cb7\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 304, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-zwgg3cb7\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 522, in run_setup
          super().run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
        File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-zwgg3cb7\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 320, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 792, in <module>
        File "<string>", line 759, in setup_package
        File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-um_nsy30\pandas_cfb0da7acd094bb49eb02e9b0460de24\versioneer.py", line 1439, in get_version
          return get_versions()["version"]
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-um_nsy30\pandas_cfb0da7acd094bb49eb02e9b0460de24\versioneer.py", line 1368, in get_versions
          cfg = get_config_from_root(root)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-um_nsy30\pandas_cfb0da7acd094bb49eb02e9b0460de24\versioneer.py", line 400, in get_config_from_root
          parser = configparser.SafeConfigParser()
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      AttributeError: module 'configparser' has no attribute 'SafeConfigParser'. Did you mean: 'RawConfigParser'?
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

It says that the error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip. But I don't understand what it means.

You are getting the DEPRECATION warning and subsequent Error message because you're trying to install an older release of this package with an unsupported python version.
You seem to be using Python 3.12 (as seen from the warning) but pandas 1.1.4 is compatible with python 3.6 - 3.9.
One way to fix this is to install the stable release of pandas which supports python 3.12 or if you must use the older version, downgrade your python to any of the supported version mentioned above.

I spent two days trying to fix this error and I think only this method works well. After looking for a stable Python version, I found one that works without error. Thank you so much for your advice, sir.

@lokalhangatt Great... Kindly accept the answer by clicking on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.
